# A php progrme is called from a html file but .php file does not run and want to save

Tags: php, html, lamp

I have installed lamp in Ubuntu 12.04 using these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and

```
$ sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

and run the following .php file in browser and it was executed by updating database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","passwd","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But when I use a .html file to connect a .php file and update mysql database the .php does not execute and want to save in a folder (Download folder as default). The .html file is:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/var/www/insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the insert.php file is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","passwd","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Did you verify that the settings for php to be recognized by apache were installed in httpd.conf?

Comment: First, try only php. Just write `<?php echo "testing php" ; ?>` If you get all contents in view source, then php is not working. Is apache running?See error logs. Have you saved inside www folder?If you struck for long time and give up, then you can try other softwares like xampp, etc. but lamp is better than xampp because xampp is for all operating systems, lamp is exclusive for linux. See, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP and use google to get more help. If you get particular error, copy that phase and google it.

Comment: @canadiancreed The file, **httpd.conf** (Directory /etc/apache2) contain  **AddType application/x-httpd-php .php**.

Comment: @web2students.com . I have tried ' <?php echo "testing php" ; ?> ' and results **testing php** in browser. Second apache is running ('$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart'). Third, WWW folder already exists in /var/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
I just modified the part of the html file to,

```
<form action="http://localhost/insert.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
action="/var/www/insert.php"
```

your path looks odd, try just

```
action="insert.php"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried 'action="insert.php"' but the same problem arise.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the path/action in your form is incorrect. You've put in the complete local path to the file, when you just need the path relative to the URL path:

```
action="insert.php"
```

Other than that, your SQL is pretty messy, won't work for multi word input and is vulnerable to injection. At least do this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[lastname])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[age])."')";
```

Or better, look into prepared statements.

Comment: I edited as you say, ' $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[lastname])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[age])."')"; ' . But same think happens.